# 1970 sci-fi story series about a spaceman looking for the group that modified him

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi, pulp

A spaceman was modified by a group that threw him out of the program before the final stage. He was a thief and soldier. He needs metal in his diet. When he is near a fully modified man, he gets a speed and power boost.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: How old were you when you read the story/ what year did you read it? Do you think it was newly published around that stage, or was it old? If so, what era was it- 60's, 70's, 80's? What type of modifications did they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Hook"](https://www.goodreads.com/series/149021-hook) series by Tully Zetford (Kenneth Bulmer)? They were published in the 70's. The character was called Hook, and was only partly modified. When he came into close proximity with the 'second generation' Boosted Men, it increased his powers.

The books in the series are:

- [*Whirlpool Of Stars*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3885293-whirlpool-of-stars) (1974)
- [*The Boosted Man*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3885290-the-boosted-man) (1974)
- [*Star City*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3885291-star-city) (1974)
- [*Virility Gene*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5117186-virility-gene) (1975)

Comment: Right time frame, right story line,  Thanks, I will have to get a copy a check it out.Thank you.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/series/149021-hook